# Tableau automatic parameter / calculated field

Tags: parameters, tableau-api, automatic-properties

I am *very* new to Tableau, and I am strugling a bit. I have a data set of measurements from an automated process looking similar to this:

```
| UNC with intial data | ... | Measurement Start | UNC with data with headers | Invalid row in the end|
```

**UNC** : Unknown number of columns which may very from different data set

What I want to do is to make 6 subsets of graph where the x axis is set, but the data for the Y-axis is taken from a list generated by the data columns and their headers. Similar to this: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/parameterized-measure - just with the measures created automatically.

Is this possible in anyway?

EDIT: 
I'll try to specify my question:

What I want is an parameter and calculated field, that allows for me to easily view all measures in the data set that ends with *_meas* in their name. Meaning, I have a standarized dashboard that views the measures accross a set of standard values (Supply voltage, frequency, dutcycle etc.) and a dropdown list that allows me to change the measures. I would like that the parameter and calculated field was created automatically, and not something I have to hard-code every time I change a measures name or the number of measures I have imported.

Comment: Can you explain it better? Give a table sample, and what you would expect the result to be

Comment: I can try, yes. Sorry if it's a little unclear. [I have tried creating a picture album to explain it a little bit better.](http://imgur.com/a/fJrzo) - basically I am trying to make a dropdown list, where each data is selected, such that you can easily view any parameter on the same dashboard. Please feel free to ask more, if its still unclear.

Comment: Still very confusing, but I'll make a guess

Comment: I've tried describing my question in a new way. Thank you so much for trying to understand. Combining not having English as my first language and learning the terms of a new program, I am strugling to even formulate my question correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what you want is to select an item in a dropdown list, which represents a measure, and plot that measure in different charts.

If that is the case, it is pretty simple. You already have the dropdown list, using a parameter, TestNames.

Now, create a calculated field, named Measure, and do it like this:

```
CASE [TestNames]
WHEN 'Measure A' THEN [Measure A]
...
END
```

This way, Measure will actually get the value of the measure you select in the list

Comment: This works well if you only want to see one of the 6 measures at a time (since a parameter can only hold a single value). If you want to see multiple graphs side by side, you'll need other approaches. Dashboards are the main way to combine multiple charts into a single viz.